# How can I verify if some data is truly the decrypted counterpart of a byte sequence?

Tags: encryption, tls

In more detail: I want to build a proxy that receives decrypted data from a client, and is able to verify that this data is what an origin server sent to the client.
For example, a client establishes a connection with an HTTPS server, proxying through this proxy. The client will send some web responses coming from the origin web server back to the proxy, which in turn has to decide whether those are really the unencrypted version of the stream that could observe previously (encrypted).

Comment: I don't fully understand why the client should go out of it's way to feed to proxy with plaintext... normal clients don't do that.

Comment: It's just an experiment I want to do, not based on what clients usually do.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like the "franking tag" for WhatsApp messages. Here's a podcast explaining this, although I have to admit I do not fully understand the details: https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-569.htm Search for "franking tag" in the text.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible.

The only known way to check if plaintext and ciphertext match (with a modern algo like AES) is to encrypt/decrypt, and for that the key is necessary. (Even more, there is no known way to decide if the ciphertext really is encrypted data (any data) or just random garbage.)

Answer (score 1):

### Decrypt and compare

In a proper cryptosystem, having a candidate of plaintext shouldn't and doesn't meaningfully help decrypting a message - either you can decrypt it by having the proper keys, or you can not.

Furthermore, there certainly can be cryptosystems that can provide multiple valid, meaningful decryption options for different keys. It's not the case for the common HTTPS protocol, but there are deniable encryption systems for hard drive encryption and messaging. In that case, you can't even make this verification by having a proper key that decrypts the cyphertext to the plaintext that you have; since it also might have another additional encrypted message.

But for HTTPS proxy, you'd need to decrypt the captured data with the proper session key and compare the results - or, in a symmetric manner, encrypt the known plaintext with that session key and compare it with the expected cyphertext. Obtaining the session key is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: is there a way to know that the client was actually able to decrypt the data, from the proxy's perspective (in a trusted way, so the client cannot claim that did but didn't)?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other two answers, you can't really decrypt the messages without knowing the keys. Also, you might run into ethical problems if you do use this design outside of your experiment.

Based on your comments, you want to ensure that the client can't deny having decrypted they text if they have successfully done so. This is not really possible to achieve either. Assuming you(the proxy) were able to decrypt the text that came from the server, if you don't trust the client you can't trust them to send you the correct decrypted text for verification.

In your case, the safest way would be to test the proxy properly and then ask for logs whenever the client complains about not being able to decrypt the text.